# When to close Cursor used in SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, searchview, android-cursor

I'm using a SimpleCursorAdapter to display results in a ListView but since I've got to query my database lots of times during a search (using the SearchView widget) it worries me that the cursor might be left opened.

This is how I query my database and show the results in a ListView:

```
class SearchCustomers extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Cursor>{

        @Override
        protected Cursor doInBackground(String... params) {         
            //get the query
            String query=params[0].toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            Cursor cursor=mDB.searchCustomersByName((query != null ? query : "@@@@"));
            return cursor;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {           

            if (result != null) {

                String[] from = new String[] { QuickOrderDB.ID,
                        QuickOrderDB.NAME,
                        QuickOrderDB.ADDRESS,
                        QuickOrderDB.PHONE_NUMBER };

                int[] to = new int[] { R.id.customerIDTextView,
                        R.id.customerNameTextView,R.id.customerAddressTextView ,
                        R.id.customerPhoneTextView };

                SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(SearchCustomersActivity.this,
                        R.layout.results_customer_item, result, from, to);
                mResultsListView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);                 

            }
        }           

    }
```

I have tried many things to close the cursor, but even If I close it after `mResultsListView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);` the result is always the same: **an empty ListView**.

I've already seen a couple of questions in which it is mentioned that the cursor will be closed automatically, but I want to make sure this is true.

**Is there any official documentation about this? Does the SimpleCursorAdapter really close the cursor automatically?**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Typically you would close it after its use and then grab another later when you need it again.

Comment: but even if I close the cursor after this part `mResultsListView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter)` the ListView won't display anything

Comment: Typically you would call `notifyDataSetChanged` on adapters in order to be sure that the information they are constructed with at a later given point in time is updated on the screen.  But there might be something else you have missing in your structure.

Comment: The only thing that worked was not to try to close the cursor. But since `mDB.searchCustomersByName` is called for every letter the user types in, it worries me that I might be causing a memory leak

Comment: if you close it after calling setAdapter, then the adapter won't have any data to get, as the cursor will be closed. close it when you don't need it anymore. hint: as long as you are displaying data from the cursor, you need the cursor open.

Comment: typically if you call `swapCursor`(?) on the adapter, the old cursor is closed.

Comment: So how will I know when I don't need the cursor anymore? I guess this will be when I leave the Activity, but I suppose I'll have to keep a reference to the Cursor then

Comment: The simpleCursor adapter is supposed to do the closing for you.  You can find more info by researching loaders. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html#onLoadFinished%28android.content.Loader%3CD%3E,%20D%29

Comment: @danny117 so there's no need to use startManagingCursor then. Will LogCat warn me If any cursor is getting leaked??

Comment: @Axel Did you find any solution to this problem? I've got the same issue and I haven't been able to find any documentation either :S

Comment: Nope :( The closest reference I've got is the provided by @danny117

Comment: I'm not closing cursors when the are used with a loader.  IDK if I'm wrong.

Comment: I think the solution is in mutating the List inside the adapter (by extending the class) instead of creating multiple adapters.

Answer (score 6):

1. You need to close your cursor once you are done with it. Closing it after setAdapter() call would prevent the adapter from accessing the data. Hence a better place to close the cursor would be during current activities tear down life cycle stages such as onPause() or onStop(). (onDestroy() should not be used as Android run-time does not guarantee calling it. I think on latest version onStop() is guaranteed)
2. I don't think SimpleCursorAdapter adapter automatically closes the cursor automatically. The official document mentions that [changeCursor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#changeCursor(android.database.Cursor))  automatically closes the old cursor, so another option could be to change your cursor after search.
   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#changeCursor(android.database.Cursor)

Answer (score 2):

It's better if you get the Cursor using a CursorLoader instead of an AsyncTask.
The Loaders are synched to the Activity/Fragment lifecycle via the LoaderManager, and the system will close the Cursor provided by the CursorLoader automatically for you when it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should close the cursor in your fragment or activity's `onPause()` callback. After the activity is paused it's possible that older Android systems will delete the app to free memory.

This implies that you need to reestablish the cursor in the corresponding `onResume()` callback.

Answer (score -3):

Don't create a variable for the cursor, just add the db query directly into the [constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[],%20int)) as the argument *`c`*, `db.query()` or a method that holds the desired query), this seems to work.

```
SimpleCursorAdapter (Context context, 
                int layout, 
                Cursor c, 
                String[] from, 
                int[] to, 
                int flags)
```