# CursorAdapter: newView and bindView never called

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I'm trying to create a `ListView` that's supposed to get populated with data retrieved from an `SQLiteDatabase`. For that purpose I've created a custom adapter, inheriting from `ResourceCursorAdapter`.
In my main Activity I've got a button which on click creates a fragment that's ought to display my list. However, though it seems I've set the adapter properly to my `ListView` (the constructor gets called) `newView` and `bindView` never get called.
I've created my adapter following this little tutorial: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter

What am I missing?

from my activity:

```
loadSnapshotsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // some static extra items
        final MatrixCursor extras = new MatrixCursor(new String[]{
                SettingsContract.PixelSnapshotEntries._ID,
                SettingsContract.PixelSnapshotEntries.SNAPSHOT_NAME,
                SettingsContract.PixelSnapshotEntries.SNAPSHOT_SIZE
        });
        extras.addRow(new String[]{"-1", "export snapshots set...", null});
        extras.addRow(new String[]{"-2", "load snapshots set...", null});
        final String[] settingsFields = new String[]{
                SettingsContract.PixelSnapshotEntries._ID,
                SettingsContract.PixelSnapshotEntries.SNAPSHOT_NAME,
                SettingsContract.PixelSnapshotEntries.SNAPSHOT_SIZE
        };
        final Cursor cursor = mDb.query(
                SettingsContract.PixelSnapshotEntries.TABLE_NAME,
                settingsFields,
                null, null, null, null, null
        );
        final Cursor[] cursors = {cursor, extras};
        final MergeCursor mergedCursor = new MergeCursor(cursors);
        Log.d(TAG, "num results: " + mergedCursor.getCount());

        SelectSnapshotFragment snapshotSelect = new SelectSnapshotFragment();
        fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.camera_preview, snapshotSelect, "snapshot select")
                .commit();
        // creation of the list view is happening in the fragment
        // in order to avoid asyncronicity issues
        snapshotSelect.setCursor(mergedCursor);
        cursor.close();
        extras.close();
    }
```

`onCreateView` from the fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.snapshots_list, container, false);
    final ListView snapshotsListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.snapshots_list);
    final SnapshotSelectAdapter adapter = new SnapshotSelectAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.snapshots_item, mCursor, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
    snapshotsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    // check for the adapter to be set properly - OK
    Log.d(TAG, "snapshots list view: " + snapshotsListView.getAdapter());
    mCursor.close();
    container.addView(view);
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

my custom adapter:

```
public class SnapshotSelectAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter {
    final private static String TAG = "SnapshotSelectAdapter";
    private int mLayout;

    public SnapshotSelectAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, c, flags);
        // cursor holds the right number of items - OK
        Log.d(TAG, "cursor: " + c.getCount());
        mLayout = layout;
    }

    // never called
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(mLayout, parent, false);
    }

    // never called either
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView row = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.snapshot_item);
        Log.d(TAG, "view: " + view + ", row: " + row);
        String text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SettingsContract.PixelSnapshotEntries.SNAPSHOT_NAME)) + " (" +
            String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SettingsContract.PixelSnapshotEntries.SNAPSHOT_SIZE))) + ")";
        row.setText(text);
    }
```

snapshots_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/snapshots_selection"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@color/colorDarkTransparentBackground"
          android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
          android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/snapshots_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

snapshots_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/snapshot_item" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I see problem in your `onCreateView` in your fragment.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.snapshots_list, container, false);
    final ListView snapshotsListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.snapshots_list);
    final SnapshotSelectAdapter adapter = new SnapshotSelectAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.snapshots_item, mCursor, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
    snapshotsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    // check for the adapter to be set properly - OK
    Log.d(TAG, "snapshots list view: " + snapshotsListView.getAdapter());
    return view
}
```

You should return view from this method, you don't need to attach to container by hand.

**Do not close cursor** in `onCreateView`, before adapter has yet to read and initialise list rows. 
Please check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30147932/4183017), in order to understand where to close the cursor.

Probably cursor closing should be happening in `onStop()` method, and then you

In the end, I would suggest against using obsolete tutorials.

Since now you could be using `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView` and `Room` instead of manually handling cursors and cursorAdapters.

If you have a very large list in your database, you could be using `Pagination` Library. 
For that I would suggest to check out [Google I/O](https://youtu.be/BE5bsyGGLf4) about lists and pagination.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have, meanwhile, already changed the return value from return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState); to return view; - however the problem persists. Also I'm closing the cursor in onStop() but that doesn't help either. 
I'm going to check out RecyclerView and Room. Is there an explicit reason why ListView shoudn't work in my case?

Comment: As I see from you comment :) It worked when you removed manual attach.

Answer (score 0):

After some struggling I think I found the solution. The problem, as far as I can see, lay within `onCreateView` of my fragment. I was explicitly attaching the view to the container. After removing that line `newView` and `bindView` where called as expected:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final ScrollView bg = (ScrollView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_background_scroll, container, false);
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.snapshots_list, bg, false);
    final ListView snapshotsListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.snapshots_list);
    final SnapshotSelectAdapter adapter = new SnapshotSelectAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.snapshots_item, mCursor, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
    snapshotsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}
```